# Accelerate large mysql join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a sql to list every day active user with its first appearance date in the log table. The *MySQL version is 5.7*.

Like:

```
date           active_users    reg_date
2020-03-1        user1        2019-02-01
2020-03-1        user2        2019-03-04
2020-03-2        user3        2019-01-18
2020-03-2        user1        2019-02-01
```

I have finished a query to achieve this, but as shown, I made 2 aggregation for the same table and then join them together... The login log table `game_user_log` comprises `2 million` rows of data and I have added index on column `data_date` and `data_date`, but my query takes about `1 minute` .

Is there any way to optimize and accelerate the query? Any help is appreciated.

This is my query:

```sql
SELECT a.data_date, a.user_id, b.reg_date 
              -- List every day and de-duplicated users
from ( SELECT distinct data_date, user_id 
       from `game_user_log`) a
              -- Get the first login date as reg_date
left outer join ( SELECT user_id, min(data_date) reg_date 
                  FROM `game_user_log` 
                  GROUP BY user_id) b
    on a.user_id=b.user_id
```

Comment: The only possible optimizations which I can find (based on your MySQL version) are: 1) replace LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN; 2) create index by `(user_id, data_date)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT data_date,
       user_id, 
       MIN(data_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) reg_date 
FROM game_user_log
GROUP BY data_date, user_id
```

?

PS. Index by `(user_id, data_date)` needed for to accelerate.

Comment: I have tried this but in this query `reg_date` always equals `data_date`

Comment: Thanks for your updating. It says error `use right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY user_id) as reg_date`. I am using MySQL 5.7 and if this is caused by version difference?

Comment: @user2894829 *I am using MySQL 5.7* Write this at the beginning of your question with the largest font which your fantasy allows.

Comment: I have updated the answer. sorry I did not realize the version difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would write your query as:

```
select du.data_date, du.user_id, u.reg_date 
from (select distinct data_date, user_id 
      from game_user_log
     ) du join
     (select user_id, min(data_date) as reg_date 
      from game_user_log
      group by user_id
     ) u
     on du.user_id = u.user_id;
```

For this query, you can try an index on `game_user_log(user_id, data_date)`.